# Android - CoverFlow, Custom Gallery - перелистывание?

Tags: customview, swipe, gallery, android

нужна помощь, как мне используя либо стандартный виджет Gallery или таким то образом сделать CoverFlow, чтоб получилось что то подобное:

[Изображение 1](http://pixs.ru/showimage/CoverFlowi_6213260_8527707.png)

[Изображение 2](http://pixs.ru/showimage/CoverFlowi_2130627_8527708.png)

[И еще возможно с таким переходом](http://pixs.ru/showimage/CoverFlowi_8436796_8527706.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо переделывать `gallery`, либо использовать сторонние карусельки: [каруселька](https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/), еще [каруселька](https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/)  и еще [одна](http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/carousel_android.php) .

Comment: Спасибо, по этим ссылкам есть то что нужно!